# Multiple Page ids in wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress function that redirects users to login when trying to view a certain page and takes that to that page once they are logged in.

The function works fine when I only put in one page id.

When I try to put in a number of page ids where the users should be redirected to login for any of these pages, the function stops working.

Please help on how I can solve this.

```
add_action('template_redirect','wpmy_check_if_logged_in');

function wpmy_check_if_logged_in(){
    $pageid = array (2295, 1589, 1031);
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page($pageid)) {
        $url = wp_login_url( get_permalink( $pageid ) );
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better for you to invent your own function which iterates over a set of IDs.

Comment: thanks but are you able to guide in achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than repeatedly call is_page() with an ID, I'd just grab the ID from the global $post object and see if it's in your array:

```
add_action('template_redirect','wpmy_check_if_logged_in');

function wpmy_check_if_logged_in(){
    $pageid = array (2295, 1589, 1031);
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page()) {
        global $post;
        if (in_array($post->ID, $pageid)) {
            $url = wp_login_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) );
            wp_redirect($url);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_page()` in a for loop:

`$pages_id` is an array.

```
function is_in_pages($pages_id)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($pages_id); $i++)
    {
       if(is_page($pages_id[$i]) == true)
       {
          return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Check it, please report the result.

Comment: so do I add to my code above or..sorry i'm quite a beginner at php and wordpress

Comment: You should add this function at the top of you wordpress header file. Test it, and if it works then I tell you a proper place for it.

Comment: no it doesnt work.. once the user logs in it takes them to the homepage rather than the page before the login

Comment: You should just use my function in place of is_page() and not your whole code. You code is OK and you just need to replace is_page with the above function.